# Reverse Textbox Multiline

Tags: vb.net

I have Textbox.Lines

```
2
4
3
9
```

> Expected Output:

```
9 
3
4
2
```

How do i that work that code? That code worked for Text Length not for Lines.

```
Public Sub ReverseText(ByVal Textbx As TextBox)
    Dim sOutput As String = ""
    For i = Textbx.TextLength - 1 To 0 Step -1
        sOutput &= Textbx.Text.ElementAt(i)
    Next
    Textbx.Text = sOutput
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Lines` property of the `TextBox` to get each line of text.

A simple modification to your code to go through each of these lines should solve your issue:

```
Public Sub ReverseText(ByVal Textbx As TextBox)
    Dim sOutput(Textbx.Lines.Length) As String
    Dim Count As Integer = 0

    For i = Textbx.Lines.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        sOutput(Count) = Textbx.Lines(i)
        Count += 1
    Next

    Textbx.Lines = sOutput
End Sub
```

In the above code, a new `array` of `string` is created named `sOutput`.

Each of the `Lines` in the `TextBox` is then added to the `sOutput` array in reverse order.

Finally, the `Lines` of the `TextBox` are updated with the new, reversed `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer is correct. Though, you can use a built-in function to reverse the order of an array like this :

```
Public Sub ReverseText(ByVal Textbx As TextBox)
    Textbx.Lines = Textbx.Lines.Reverse.ToArray 
End Sub
```